# What can we do against fake pages spoofing our site?

Tags: google-index, mirror

There is a malicious agent who is creating crude fake versions of my employer's website. Even if they made a really bad copy there are still people falling for it. And nothing prevents them from setting up different and better versions.

What we currently do is:

- [Report it](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93713?hl=en) to Google index.
- Report it to the [FCA](https://www.fca.org.uk/)

Is there anything that we can do to reduce the risk?

Comment: What "people" are falling for it?

Comment: There are many places to report phishing URLs so that they make it to phishing blacklists.

Comment: Report to the domain registrar, and the hosting provider. They are usually helpful.

Comment: This doesn't look like a security issue or even a phishing issue. Someone is just copying your site.

Comment: @schroeder Transfering real money to "invest"

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! This is a very serious issue. If this was my company, my attorney would be on it already. I suggest that your employer contact an attorney immediately. This is not simply a one faceted issue. This is outright and intentional theft in a whole host of ways. This question may be better suited on https://law.stackexchange.com/. We are not lawyers here. They would have a better idea of what legal rights and options you have. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc First we would need to know who did it. It may be someone in North Korea or Venezuela.

Comment: A lawyer who specializes in Internet Law can figure it out quickly and easily as well as what options exist. Generally, they get results fast.